# System.TypeInitializationException abstract class first access

Tags: c#

I just really get stucked with this silly thing.

```
abstract class Texture
{
    static Dictionary<string, int> textures = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public static Dictionary<string, int> Textures { get { return textures; } set { textures = value; } }
    public static int GetTexture(string name)
    {
        return Texture.Textures[name];
    }
    public static void LoadTexture(string name, string filename)
    {
        int id = GL.GenTexture();
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, id);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename);
        BitmapData bmp_data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, bmp_data.Width, bmp_data.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bmp_data.Scan0);

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmp_data);

        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
        Textures.Add(name, id);
    } 
    static Texture()
    {
        LoadTexture("some_name", "some_name.jpg");
    }
}
```

It causes error when I try to get a value from Dictionary. Accessing somewhere in the build:

```
 textureObjects.Add(name, Texture.GetTexture(name));
```

The error says that I acccessing the forbidden memmory(protected). But I don't actually do it...

Comment: `Texture` is an abstract class, so `textureObjects` isn't an instance of it.  You may be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: show all relevant code.. what is `GL` in this line `int id = GL.GenTexture();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception generally means that an error was throw in the static constructor (or one of the static field initializers) of your class.  My guess is that an exception was thrown in the call to `GL.GenTexture()`.  Check the `InnerException` property of the exception to see more detail.

**EDIT**

Not that you've added more code I see that there are several places where that exception could be thrown.  The answer is still to determine where the exception is being thrown in `LoadTexture` and fix that.

Comment: yeah GL.GenTexture() causes the error. I'm trying to access/write in "protected" memmory. Somethin like that I don't init GL.

Comment: I would probably try to avoid calling that in the static constructor if it's not necessary - those errors can be hard to debug.